# Problem with Liquidity installation

Tags: smart-contracts, liquidity

After entering this command `make build-deps` , I get the error message:

```
The following dependencies couldn't be met:
  - liquidity → ocaml < 4.07.1
      no matching version

No solution found, exiting
Makefile:61: recipe for target 'build-deps' failed
make: *** [build-deps] Error 20
```

What should I do? Help, please

Comment: Try running `eval $(opam env)` and then `make` again.

Comment: I just tried to reinstall everything from scratch and there was no such error, but thanks for the advice anyway